# Keycloak with angular authgaurd

Tags: angular, keycloak

I am following  example here [keycloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/fc6d6ff7f7dae7fb25edf052659d18cd8de55a5f/examples/demo-template/angular2-product-app/src/main/webapp)

I have two components - appComponent and Dashboard.

Route in app-routing-module:

```
  { path: 'accnt/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,  canActivate : [ AuthGuardService ] },
```

AuthGaurd Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService  implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private rtr:Router, private kc: KeycloakService) { }

   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
 
    if (KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn) {
   
      return true;

    } else {
         return KeycloakService.init();
    }

  }
}
```

Keycloak Service:

```
export class KeycloakService {
  static auth: any = {};

  constructor() { }

  static init(): Promise<any> {
    let keycloakAuth: any = new Keycloak('keycloak.json');
    KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = false;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })
        .success(() => {
          KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = true;
          KeycloakService.auth.authz = keycloakAuth;
          KeycloakService.auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.authServerUrl + "/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=/angular2-product/index.html";
          resolve(true);
        })
        .error(() => {
          reject(false);
        });
    });
  }
```

This works. When accessing the  dashboard, it redirects to keycloak. However, after login, it shows appComponent rather than dashboard.

URL shows

```
http://localhost:4200/#state=e9be6204-6cd8-4401-8111-cd4a13dce711&session_state=d0cb348f-a681-45bf-aa68-e0f64b2deddc&code=8156fb04-fa37-4afa-8c25-14fc2789c999.d0cb348f-a681-45bf-aa68-e0f64b2deddc.c7b376cb-05a2-49fa-8164-b8c932598bbd
```

I can check the token so login has been successful

If I again click on Dashboard, it shows Dashboard component. I know this happens because whole angular app gets reloaded. Is there a standard way of solving this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When you save data in the service, the data is not persistent. You need to use local storage and save JWT token. Using this mechanism you can check whether the user is already logged in or out.

If the user is already logged in, check the localStorage status and pass authenticate user to dashboard else init the authentication system and then allow user to land on the home page.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

 // change it to persistent
 // localStorage returns the string type, you need to convert it to 
 // boolean first to check if it is true or false

 const isAuth = localStorage.getItem('isUserAuth'); // return nothing if the key doesn't exist

    if (isAuth) {
      return true;
    } else {
         return KeycloakService.init();
    }

  }
```

In your `KeycloakService` service, it is a pseudo code for the understanding not the actual code:

```
userAuthentication(passAuthenticationStatus) {

   //check if user is authenticated
   // run your authentication flow before this method
   // once you get token or any authentication
   // set authentication to true in localStorage

   if (passAuthenticationStatus) {
      localStorage.setItem('isUserAuth', JSON.stringify(true));
   } else {
      // check why user is not authenticated
   }
}
```